# Propriedades do material design não aparecem em aparelho de API 19

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, app-compat-v7

Eu adicionei a biblioteca de suporte para APIs abaixo da 21 e estou testando a propriedade `elevation` nos meus componentes.

Na visualização do layout, quando clico na aba de design, eu consigo ver a elevação mas quando executo para meu smartphone não muda nada, continua tudo sem elevação nenhuma.

Antes de adicionar o suporte eu não conseguia nem usar a propriedade, então não entendo como agora consigo usar e não funciona.

Adicionei as linhas em `dependencies`, no gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No que diz respeito ao *"Material Design"* nem tudo é [suportado pela *appcompat*](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#SupportLib).

No caso da `elevation`, ela só é parcialmente implementada.

A *appcompat* permite a utilização da propriedade, mas ela não é renderizada em versões inferiores à API21.
O método [setElevation()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.java/#697), da classe *android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat*, é implementado da seguinte forma(sem nada dentro):

```
@Override
public void setElevation(View view, float elevation) {

}
```

Assim, o código é compatível com as versões inferiores, mas o efeito da *elevation* só é visível em dispositivos Android com API21 ou superior.
O método é reescrito na [implementação referente à API21](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.java#1163) assim:

```
@Override
public void setElevation(View view, float elevation) {

    ViewCompatApi21.setElevation(view, elevation);

}
```

Comment: Então não existe uma maneira de eu ter esse efeito do elevation em APIs inferiores a 21? Porque eu consigo perceber a sombra em alguns aplicativos que tenho instalado no smartphone. Eles usaram algum outro recurso?

Comment: Sim, possivelmente recorrendo a *9-Patch drawables*, veja [isto](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-materialshadowninepatch)

Comment: Muito obrigada! Só mais uma dúvida: usando esses efeitos eu não preciso do elevation do Material né?

Comment: Sim, segundo diz lá correm da API9 em diante