# Elevation em Botão não está mostrando a Sombra

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Olá,
Estou tentando usar **Elevation** nos botões da seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não está funcionando, o Elevation não está formando sombra.

Segue o XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="kiraitami.krtbeta03.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toobar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:background="#13000000"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg_mountain"
    android:layout_width="462dp"
    android:layout_height="777dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/mountain"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg_diagonal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="485dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/diagonal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.231"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bg_mountain"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.818" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_damage"
    android:layout_width="311dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="212dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/damagebtn"
    android:onClick="startDamageActivity"
    android:text="BOTAO 1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_audio"
    android:layout_width="311dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/audiobtn"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:text="BOTAO 3"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_notes2"
    android:layout_width="311dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/notesbtn"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:text="BOTAO 2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS.: O único lugar em que a elevation está funcionando é na Toolbar

O que devo fazer para consertar isso?

Comment: Já tentou colocar tudo dentro de um LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 1):

Ao atribuir um *background* ao botão este irá perder algumas das sua características.
Entre elas estão a elevação e a animação ao ser clicado.

Por outro lado, mesmo sem atribuir um `background` não é possível alterar a elevação apenas atribuindo um valor através de `android:elevation`.

A elevação, nos diferentes estados de um botão(Enabled, Disabled, Focused, Pressed) é controlada por um StateListAnimator.

Assim, para alterar a elevação terá de construir o seu próprio StateListAnimator ou atribuir null a `android:stateListAnimator`.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
android:elevation="20dp"
```

No seu caso sugiro que em vez de atribuir a imagem ao backgroud use `android:drawableLeft`.

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_notes2"
    android:layout_width="311dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/notesbtn"
    android:text="BOTAO 2"/>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nota:** O efeito da [elevation não é visível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147865/2541) em dispositivos Android com API inferior à 21.

Comment: Vou tentar!
Muito Obrigado!!!